# Follow=true alternative for logback logger

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j, logback

In log4j you can set the property "follow=true" on a logger to make sure the logs are send to a new version of e.g. System.out.

Is there an alternative when using logback?

I'm trying to follow the javadoc of OutputCaptureExtension.java

```
To reliably capture output from Log4j2, set the follow attribute 
of the console appender to true:
  <Appenders>
      <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
          ...
      </Console>
   </Appenders>
```